# Unable to wire using ActiveProfile annotation

Tags: spring, spring-annotations, spring-profiles

First time using Profiles and need help.
I have an abstract base class (DecisionManagementRuleExecutor) that gets its dependency (RuleHandler) wired through annotation.

```
    @Component
    public class RuleHandler {......

   public abstract class DecisionManagementRuleExecutor<M extends PersistentEntity,T extends Response> implements RuleExecutor<M,T>{

   @Autowired
   RuleHandler ruleHandler;
```

When I run with 'itest' profile, I want 'ITestRuleHandler' a child of 'RuleHandler' to be wired. 
Where 'ItestRuleHandler' is

```
    @Component
    @ActiveProfiles(value = "itest")
    public class ITestRuleHandler extends RuleHandler {
```

I see that in the logs that active profile is 'itest'

```
    System.getProperty("spring.profiles.active")
```

I am pasting the log for the wiring

> Processing injected element of bean 'vendorServiceRuleExecutor': AutowiredFieldElement for c.a.p.d.RuleHandler c.a.p.d.s.DecisionManagementRuleExecutor.ruleHandler
>          Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'ITestRuleHandler'
>          Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'ruleHandler'
>          Creating instance of bean 'ruleHandler'
>          Eagerly caching bean 'ruleHandler' to allow for resolving potential circular references
>          Finished creating instance of bean 'ruleHandler'
>          Autowiring by type from bean name 'vendorServiceRuleExecutor' to bean named 'ruleHandler'
>          Finished creating instance of bean 'vendorServiceRuleExecutor'

Edit:
Changed the 'RuleHandler' as an interface and now I am getting this error:

```
  No qualifying bean of type [c.a.p.d.RuleHandler] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: ITestRuleHandler,iTestRuleHandler
```

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the implementation `ITestRuleHandler` available for the `itest` profile, you need to declare your class as:

```
@Component
@Profile("itest")
public class ITestRuleHandler extends RuleHandler
```

`@ActiveProfiles` activates one or more profiles, not expose a component for a profile.  This should be applied to one of the test (or consuming) classes to activate a profile for testing (or consumption).